# Elasticsearch master node constantly connecting and disconnecting

Tags: elasticsearch, networking, rackspace

I'm constantly getting these error messages in my logs:

```
[2015-11-10 13:52:03,037][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [ClusterUK Node 1] [11] failed send ping to [ClusterUK Node 1][x-eBYFoiRemOBK7egMHTRg][elasticuk1][inet[/172.24.32.10:9300]]{master=true}
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalStateException: can't add nodes to a stopped transport
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:746)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:731)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:216)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing$3.run(UnicastZenPing.java:376)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2015-11-10 13:52:03,038][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [ClusterUK Node 1] [12] failed send ping to [ClusterUK Node 1][x-eBYFoiRemOBK7egMHTRg][elasticuk1][inet[/172.24.32.10:9300]]{master=true}
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalStateException: can't add nodes to a stopped transport
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:746)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:731)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:216)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing$3.run(UnicastZenPing.java:376)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2015-11-10 13:52:03,038][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [ClusterUK Node 1] [12] failed send ping to [ClusterUK Node 1][x-eBYFoiRemOBK7egMHTRg][elasticuk1][inet[/172.24.32.10:9300]]{master=true}
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalStateException: can't add nodes to a stopped transport
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:746)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:731)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:216)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing$3.run(UnicastZenPing.java:376)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2015-11-10 13:52:11,378][INFO ][transport                ] [ClusterUK Node 1] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/172.24.32.10:9300]}
[2015-11-10 13:52:11,394][INFO ][discovery                ] [ClusterUK Node 1] ClusterUK/FTiLxRmZQLyFtyap8JTj2w
[2015-11-10 13:52:14,498][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ClusterUK Node 1] detected_master [ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true}, added {[ClusterUK Client Node STG1][_JfbrXjFTzGD7BL7OTqbVA][Staging1][inet[/192.168.100.248:9300]]{data=false, master=false},[ClusterUK Node 3][rHJ486YyQHqKytG44fmC7g][elasticuk3][inet[/172.24.32.8:9300]]{master=true},[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true}])
[2015-11-10 13:52:14,749][INFO ][http                     ] [ClusterUK Node 1] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/172.24.32.10:9200]}
[2015-11-10 13:52:14,750][INFO ][node                     ] [ClusterUK Node 1] started
[2015-11-10 13:52:44,994][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [ClusterUK Node 1] master_left [[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true}], reason [do not exists on master, act as master failure]
[2015-11-10 13:52:44,996][WARN ][discovery.zen            ] [ClusterUK Node 1] master left (reason = do not exists on master, act as master failure), current nodes: {[ClusterUK Client Node STG1][_JfbrXjFTzGD7BL7OTqbVA][Staging1][inet[/192.168.100.248:9300]]{data=false, master=false},[ClusterUK Node 1][FTiLxRmZQLyFtyap8JTj2w][elasticuk1][inet[elasticuk1/172.24.32.10:9300]]{master=true},[ClusterUK Node 3][rHJ486YyQHqKytG44fmC7g][elasticuk3][inet[/172.24.32.8:9300]]{master=true},}
[2015-11-10 13:52:44,996][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ClusterUK Node 1] removed {[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true},}, reason: zen-disco-master_failed ([ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true})
[2015-11-10 13:52:48,047][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ClusterUK Node 1] detected_master [ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true}, added {[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true}])
[2015-11-10 13:53:10,689][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ClusterUK Node 1] removed {[ClusterUK Node 3][rHJ486YyQHqKytG44fmC7g][elasticuk3][inet[/172.24.32.8:9300]]{master=true},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true}])
[2015-11-10 13:53:13,199][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ClusterUK Node 1] added {[ClusterUK Node 3][rHJ486YyQHqKytG44fmC7g][elasticuk3][inet[/172.24.32.8:9300]]{master=true},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true}])
[2015-11-10 13:53:35,963][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [ClusterUK Node 1] master_left [[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true}], reason [transport disconnected]
[2015-11-10 13:53:35,964][WARN ][discovery.zen            ] [ClusterUK Node 1] master left (reason = transport disconnected), current nodes: {[ClusterUK Client Node STG1][_JfbrXjFTzGD7BL7OTqbVA][Staging1][inet[/192.168.100.248:9300]]{data=false, master=false},[ClusterUK Node 1][FTiLxRmZQLyFtyap8JTj2w][elasticuk1][inet[elasticuk1/172.24.32.10:9300]]{master=true},[ClusterUK Node 3][rHJ486YyQHqKytG44fmC7g][elasticuk3][inet[/172.24.32.8:9300]]{master=true},}
[2015-11-10 13:53:35,965][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ClusterUK Node 1] removed {[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true},}, reason: zen-disco-master_failed ([ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true})
[2015-11-10 13:53:39,018][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ClusterUK Node 1] detected_master [ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true}, added {[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true}])
[2015-11-10 13:54:03,581][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [ClusterUK Node 1] master_left [[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true}], reason [transport disconnected]
[2015-11-10 13:54:03,581][WARN ][discovery.zen            ] [ClusterUK Node 1] master left (reason = transport disconnected), current nodes: {[ClusterUK Client Node STG1][_JfbrXjFTzGD7BL7OTqbVA][Staging1][inet[/192.168.100.248:9300]]{data=false, master=false},[ClusterUK Node 1][FTiLxRmZQLyFtyap8JTj2w][elasticuk1][inet[elasticuk1/172.24.32.10:9300]]{master=true},[ClusterUK Node 3][rHJ486YyQHqKytG44fmC7g][elasticuk3][inet[/172.24.32.8:9300]]{master=true},}
[2015-11-10 13:54:03,581][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ClusterUK Node 1] removed {[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true},}, reason: zen-disco-master_failed ([ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true})
[2015-11-10 13:54:06,603][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ClusterUK Node 1] detected_master [ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true}, added {[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true}])
[2015-11-10 13:54:39,790][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [ClusterUK Node 1] master_left [[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true}], reason [transport disconnected]
[2015-11-10 13:54:39,792][WARN ][discovery.zen            ] [ClusterUK Node 1] master left (reason = transport disconnected), current nodes: {[ClusterUK Client Node STG1][_JfbrXjFTzGD7BL7OTqbVA][Staging1][inet[/192.168.100.248:9300]]{data=false, master=false},[ClusterUK Node 1][FTiLxRmZQLyFtyap8JTj2w][elasticuk1][inet[elasticuk1/172.24.32.10:9300]]{master=true},[ClusterUK Node 3][rHJ486YyQHqKytG44fmC7g][elasticuk3][inet[/172.24.32.8:9300]]{master=true},}
[2015-11-10 13:54:39,792][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ClusterUK Node 1] removed {[ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true},}, reason: zen-disco-master_failed ([ClusterUK Node 2][T5R_1SUwRu6Q4zZLMTbNlA][elasticuk2][inet[/172.24.32.5:9300]]{master=true})
[2015-11-10 13:54:42,366][ERROR][marvel.agent.exporter    ] [ClusterUK Node 1] remote target didn't respond with 200 OK response code [503 Service Unavailable]. content: [:)
��error�ClusterBlockException[blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/2/no master];]��status$��]
```

That'd be my `elasticsearch.yml` file:

```
action.disable_delete_all_indices: true

cluster.name: ClusterUK

network.publish_host: "172.24.32.10"

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.24.32.10", "172.24.32.5", "172.24.32.8"]

indices.fielddata.cache.size: 25%
indices.cluster.send_refresh_mapping: false

node.name: "ClusterUK Node 1" 
node.master: true
node.data: true

bootstrap.mlockall: true
```

In some cases it leave Elasticsearch not running as a service (few seconds).

This is currently running in Rackspace and I think there might be network issues involved (However, I'm binding to a specific IP address and use unicast).

There are 4 nodes running there (3 with master=true and data=true and one client node).

Can someone give me an insight on what's actually happening there? Version 1.7.3 (client node 1.7.1) on Windows Server.

I'm suspecting that issue comes from `master left (reason = transport disconnected)` and it's a split-brain, but how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find what was the issue. Elasticsearch doesn't tolerate [TCP Offloading](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/disabling-tcp-offloading-in-windows-server-2012).

> TCP offload engine is a function used in network interface cards (NIC)
>   to offload processing of the entire TCP/IP stack to the network
>   controller. By moving some or all of the processing to dedicated
>   hardware, a TCP offload engine frees the system's main CPU for other
>   tasks. However, TCP offloading has been known to cause some issues,
>   and disabling it can help avoid these issues.

#### Disable TCP Offloading

1. In the Windows server, open the Control Panel and select **Network
   Settings** > **Change Adapter Settings**.

[image: Screenshot]

2. Right-click on each of the adapters (**private** and **public**), select
   **Configure** from the **Networking** menu, and then click the **Advanced** tab.
   The TCP offload settings are listed for the Citrix adapter.

[image: Screenshot]

3. Disable each of the following TCP offload options, and then click
   **OK**:

   - IPv4 Checksum Offload
   - Large Receive Offload
   - Large Send Offload
   - TCP Checksum Offload

This solved my issue.